# Why Angular doesn't ask me about css and routing permissions?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli, angular-router

I run in terminal this command `$ng new my-app`. It should ask me some permissions like routing and CSS styles. It doesn't ask me and create `my-app` directly.

What is wrong here?

```
npm version: 8.5.0
node version: 16.14.2
Angular cli version: 14.0.2
```

I tried to run `$ng r -g @angular/cli` and install it again but it does again not work as expected by me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem accrued when I use any terminal else (Like `git Bash`), when I use default `windows terminal (CMD)` it's run correctly as I expected!

> I don't know why this can run with windows terminal correctly and doesn't run with another correctly, but it works!

Comment: probably you have not added angular in your system environment and hence, it is available only in the terminal type, in which you installed angular.